# Adding X-meli-session-id Header in MercadoPago SDK

Tags: pci-compliance, mercadopagosdk

My requirement is to add ***X-meli-session-id*** Header in the payment request to MercadoPago, but i cant find a way to add a extra header, I'm using mercadopago SKD "dx-java-1.0.33" and the request is done just calling

```
payment.save();
```

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I updated the SDK to 1.2.1. This versions has an option to create a payment with an object "MPRequestOptions" in the constructor of save method as follow:

```
MPRequestOptions mpRequestOptions = MPRequestOptions.createDefault();
    customHeaders.put("X-meli-session-id",deviceId);
    mpRequestOptions.setCustomHeaders(customHeaders);

    payment.save(mpRequestOptions);
```

Regards